# How to remotely submit a form through PHP?

Tags: php, curl

How can I remotely submit a web form with POST variables using PHP 5.2?

Comment: Since you have (correctly) tagged it `curl`, have you already *tried* anything?

Comment: @deceze No. I know that curl is involved but don't know exactly what I have to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a *very* basic POST curl

```
$data = array(
    'submit' => 'submit',
    'field_1' => 'bleh'
);

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$result = curl_exec();
```